# variable not substituted correctly when using arrays in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, hadoop, awk

I want to capture size of hadoop file and then based on its value, i want do my processing. I have written some unix script, but not working as intended.

```
#!/bin/sh
VAR=$(hadoop fs -ls /user/smike/del | sed 1d | awk '{ print $NF }' | paste -sd, | sed 's/,/ /g')
FVAR=$VAR
array1=($FVAR)
a=""
b=""
for i in "${array1[@]}"
do
echo "$i"
#var1=$(hadoop fs -dus /user/smike/del/$i|awk '{ print $(NF-1) }')
var1=$(hadoop fs -ls /user/smike/del/$i|awk '{ print $(NF-3) }')

echo "Size of the file is $var1"
if [ $var1 -gt 0]; then
a="$a $i"
else
b="$b $i"
fi
done
echo "$a"
echo "$b"
```

when i see my nohup file, the substitution for following line is 
var1=$(hadoop fs -ls /user/smike/del/$i|awk '{ print $(NF-3) }')

```
+ echo /user/smike/del/2
/user/smike/del/2
+ awk '{ print $(NF-3) }' + hadoop fs -ls /user/smike/del//user/smike/del/2
16/08/18 20:16:28 INFO hdfs.PeerCache: SocketCache disabled.
ls: `/user/smike/del//user/smike/del/2': No such file or directory
```

I do not know why it is substituting in this way. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: is `#!/bin/sh` deliberate? use `#!/bin/bash` if you want a `bash` script... `[ $var1 -gt 0]` is missing a space, should be `[ $var1 -gt 0 ]` ..

Comment: `VAR` and (especially) `FVAR` are redundant; they don't do anything beyond what `array1=$(hadoop ...)` would do.

Comment: What does the output of `hadoop fs -ls /user/smike/del` look like?

Comment: Thanks i changed to bash and also gave space after 0..but the problem is not solved.

Comment: `Found 2 items
    -rw-r--r--   3 smike smike       3079 2016-08-18 18:52 /user/smike/del/2
    -rw-r--r--   3 smike smike          0 2016-08-18 18:52 /user/smike/del/abc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The substitution looks fine; `i` just already is a full path name, and there appears to be no need to prefix it with `/user/smike/del`.

```
var1=$(hadoop fs -ls "$i" |awk '{ print $(NF-3) }')
```

Comment: Thanks Chepner. Actually iam passing /user/smike/del as a parameter from another file. I need it to be there

Comment: You may need it for the initial call that sets `VAR`, but not after that. You are already getting the full file names; prefix them with the base directory is just creating a nonexistant path names.